# How to send file from a system accessible from load balancer through attachment in mail using java?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

My two server machines are deployed behind a load balancer for high availability. When a user upload a file through browser, the file is stored on any of the server machine behind load balancer.
I want that file to send as an attachment through mail to the user using java but I don't know how to get the file path behind the load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced this problem recently, and did some research about this. The best solution that I found was to keep a shared memory on some third machine, which would be accessible by both of your server machines. The file would be read and written from that machine only. The location of the file can be either kept in central logs, or central database.

Note that the way you are trying to do this requires the two machines to communicate with each other (network communication). By doing this, you would increase the request service time. Also, you'll get rid of the "high availability" requirement because one download request will invoke both the server machines (in worst case).